# how to fix rendering problem of smooth shading object?

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, shaders, color

Here is my lamp I smooth the lamp base but when I render it shows some odd result of base but the other parts of lamp are fine when render?

[image: this is the lamp]

Comment: There are several possible problem that can cause this depending on your model.  It would help if you added your blend file to your question. (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there are two different base objects, one red smooth shaded, one grey not smoothed.

Probably you disabled the viewport visibility of the grey one, but you didn't disable it in rendering, check your outliner for multiple base objects.

Comment: yes i figured it out you are right i did not disable it in rendering. Thanks for reply